# Rspec: undefined method `all'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pagination

I have to test paginate method in my controller.

In my controller

```
@categories = Category.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page]).all(:order => 'id ASC')
```

In my spec

```
Category.should_receive(:paginate)
get :user_category, { :per_page => 1, :page => 1 }
```

In my log showing

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `all' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I make this test to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On its own, `should_receive` will stub the receiver and cause the method to return `nil`.

You can specify a return value, however:

```
Category.should_receive(:paginate).and_return(categories_mock)
```

In the later versions of RSpec, you can also set it up to still [call and use the return value of the original method](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method):

```
Category.should_receive(:paginate).and_call_original
```

**Update:**

By the way, the `all()` call with an argument is [no longer supported](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all). You can write the code this way:

```
@categories = Category.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page]).order('id ASC')
```

I personally prefer having pagination chained last because it is presentation-related.

For the stubbing, you can use [`stub_chain()`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods):

```
categories_mock = [mock_model(Category)]
Category.stub_chain(:paginate, :order).and_return(categories_mock)
```

Note that this stubbing can cause problems if you integrate your views, because the pagination helper expects a pagination object and not an array.

Comment: May we see the return value that you are passing? Also, please try `and_call_original()` if you don't mind not stubbing out pagination in your test.

Comment: `let(:categories) { [mock_model(Category)] }` `Category.should_receive(:paginate).and_return(categories)`

Comment: Is it correct that you are not getting this anymore: `undefined method "all" for nil:NilClass` but a similar exception for an array? Please see answer update.

Comment: yes,am getting like `undefined method 'all' for [#<Category:0x3fc198c1142c @name="Category_1001">]:Array`..your updated answer will make the test to pass..but will it show error when the paginate method is not included in the controller?

Comment: @SanthNish, if you change the order or omit some in the method chain, you'd have to adjust the stubbing accordingly. Regarding errors, if you do this kind of stubbing in your view specs or request specs -- anything that will actually call your paginate helpers -- you are likely to come across an error. For example, an array object does not have a `total_count` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your test should be:

```
Category.should_receive(:paginate)
get :user_category, :per_page => 1, :page => 1
```

In order to have params[:per_page]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the `will_paginate` gem.

The paginate helper performs an ActiveRecord query on your database, in your case your test environment database.

The error you get means that no objects were returned by your paginate query.

This is likely due to the fact that your test should look like

```
Category.should_receive(:paginate)
get :user_category, :per_page => 1, :page => 1
```

in order to properly set your `:per_page` param.

Also, make sure your test db works fine and you actually have some categories in it.

Comment: yes, am using will_paginate gem, also my testdb works fine, the parameter also passing..still i cant make it..